# p:inputTextarea set text at cursor position

Tags: button, primefaces, position, cursor

how can I add a predefined text at a button to my p:inputTextArea?

```
<p:commandButton onClick="setThisTextToMyInpuTextArea"
```

How can I do this?
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score -1):

a solution could be use an actionListener that call a method that set the value of the variable and then in the commandButton update this component.
something like:

```
<p:commandButton update="yourTextarea" actionListener="#{yourBean.setText}"/>
```

and the method:

```
public void setText(){
    setVar="Text";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But what is "setVar" ? Could you please post the whole code for your solution? Thank you very much